# Symfony Form FileType via AJAX: validation error isSubmitted() always false with processData: false

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

I have done file upload with `AJAX JQUERY` in the past but now I am trying to do the same with a symfony `FileType`.

The problem is that in normal workflow we need to add `contentType: false, processData: false,` but this seems to result in the following symfony error: `Cannot check if an unsubmitted form is valid. Call Form::isSubmitted() before Form::isValid().`

so `isSubmitted()` is always false and I am guessing because of `processData: false`

I am at a complete loss on how to solve this because if I do not do the `contentType: false` the AJAX request crashes. The symfony documentation has not content on this.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const form_data = $('#newBrandForm').serializeArray();
const json = serializeAsObject(form_data)

    const files = document.getElementById('new_brand_group_logo_logoFile').files;

    if (files.length > 0) {

        let formData = new FormData();

        for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            formData.append("attachements", files[x]);
        }

        json['new_brand[group_logo][logoFile]'] = formData

    }

    $.ajax({
        url: `/new-brand-form-handle`,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: json
    })
```

CONTROLLER

```
function brandFormHandle(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $brandEntity = new Brand();

    // create form
    $form = $this->createForm(NewBrandType::class, $brandEntity);

    // handle
    $form->handleRequest($request); // CRASH HERE

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 

        $brand = $form->getData();

        // move file
        $someNewFilename = 'newBrand'.'-logo';
        $file = $form['attachment']->getData();
        $file->move($this->directory, $someNewFilename);

        try {

            $em->persist($brand);
            $em->flush();

            $status = 'Brand added';

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return $this->json([2, 'insertion error'.$ex]);
        }
        return $this->json([1, $status]);
    }

 //....

}
```

`$request` DUMP So I can see the files in there but looks like the form is just an Object so I am not sure if that could be the problem ?

```
Request {#51 ▼
+attributes: ParameterBag {#71 ▶}
+request: ParameterBag {#87 ▼
#parameters: array:1 [▼
  "form" => "[object Object]"
]
}
+query: ParameterBag {#70 ▶}
+server: ServerBag {#35 ▶}
+files: FileBag {#73 ▶}
+cookies: ParameterBag {#72 ▶}
+headers: HeaderBag {#82 ▶}
#content: null
#languages: null
#charsets: null
#encodings: null
#acceptableContentTypes: null
#pathInfo: "/new-brand-form-handle"
#requestUri: "/new-brand-form-handle"
#baseUrl: ""
#basePath: null
#method: "POST"
#format: null
#session: Closure {#111 ▶}
#locale: null
#defaultLocale: "en"
-isHostValid: true
-isForwardedValid: true
basePath: ""
format: "html"
}
```

// this is the dump from the console.log(json) , notice there is no file; Im not sure if that is normal

```
Object
 new_brand[group_description][description]: "description"
 new_brand[group_identification][city]: ""
 new_brand[group_identification][country]: "AU"
 new_brand[group_identification][name]: "name"
 new_brand[group_identification][postcode]: ""
 new_brand[group_identification][streetAdd]: ""
 new_brand[group_identification][street]: "street"
 new_brand[group_identification][website]: "website"
 new_brand[group_logo][logoURL]: "web"
```

Comment: what happens when you submit the form without the files?

Comment: Most likely, the problem is within your Symfony controller, not the javascript - show us how you handle form submission. Also, take a look at this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20013#issuecomment-341933962

Comment: @iiirxs without files no problem

Comment: @Domagoj I added the PHP code

Comment: could you use console.log(json); just before your ajax call to tell us what properties and values has the json object? This seems totally like an invalid data error in your ajax call and not at all like an issue in your controller

Comment: @iiirxs added to the question, it is an object

Comment: where is new_brand[group_logo][logoFile] attribute?

Comment: in any case i am going to answer how to solve this issue in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are mixing different approaches (using serializeArray alongside FormData), and don't just stick to FormData.

It seems that you are passing a wrongly formatted json object as data in your ajax request as the field json['new_brand[group_logo][logoFile]'] contains formData and thus it's not a valid json object.

In fact if you are using twig to render your form (which I guess you do), all you have to do is:

```
var form = $('#newBrandForm')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
    url: `/new-brand-form-handle`,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData
});
```

Now you should have your form properly submitted in your controller.